# How to use grouped data from ag-grid to show a external div tree structure like treant.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tree, ag-grid

I am having json data from api coming into ag-grid; on which i am playing with it to group columns into various ways and data is grouped as per user order of columns grouped.

On top of it, post the data is grouped i want to draw the tree structure like below:

[Collapsible tree](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/collapsable/)

[Connector Tree](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/examples/connectors/)

Any ideas how to use the processed data to create above tree structures?